# npm install but in package-lock, npmjs changes to yarnpkg

Tags: node.js, npm, dependencies, yarnpkg, package-lock.json

What I did:

1. Git pull from main
2. run `nvm use` to use node v14.17.6 (npm v6.14.15) then `npm install`
3. delete package-lock.json then run `npm install` again

After steps 2 and 3, for some dependencies package-lock.json, npmjs changed to yarnpkg.

[image: Github Desktop after step 3]

Questions:

1. Why did this happen since this project does not use yarn
2. How can I fix this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this -

`npm cache clear - -force`
`npx rimraf ./**/node_modules`
`del package-lock.json`

now run `npm install` again

Comment: thank you it works!